# Resetting password via email

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

sorry for the long post, I'm trying to reset password via email, until now I managed to send the reset link to the email, right now I tried this in the backend:

```
userRouter.get('/reset', expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      resetPasswordToken: req.query.resetPasswordToken,
      resetPasswordExpires: {
        $gt: Date.now(),
      },
    },
  });
  if (user) {
    console.log('token matched')
    res.status(200).send({
      message: 'password reset link ok'
    })
  } else {
    console.log('password reset link is invalid or has expired');
    res.json('password reset link is invalid or has expired');
  }
})
);
```

In the forgot password I did something like this for updating the two field:

```
user.update({
        resetPasswordToken: token,
        resetPasswordExpires: Date.now() + 360000,
      });
```

My user Model is:

```
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true }
```

When I'm trying to use the where clause to check the resetPasswordToken is returning all my users, which is wrong. I'm thinking that I need to declare the resetPasswordToken and resetPasswordExpires in the model for it two work? Or it is enough? Another question would be, what would I have to send to the frontend so it will work?

In react-redux, I have the following function, but I'm 100%, that I'm sending the wrong data:

```
export const checktoken = (email) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: USER_RESET_PASSWORD_REQUEST, payload: { email } });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/users/reset');
    dispatch({ type: USER_RESET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, payload: data });;
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_RESET_PASSWORD_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't understand. Too long a question. Which part are you asking? Backend? Front end? Resetting Password? Verifying Password? Entering into Database? Redux? You are throwing everything into one single question.

Comment: If you would have actually read the question, you would have known that I'm asking if i should update the model or if I need to do something else.

Comment: Now that make sense. (should probably omit the react part). Please see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Your model doesn't have the field `resetPasswordToken` and `resetPasswordExpires`. Which means your `update` will not work. I'm assuming you are using mongoose, and mongoose will not update fields that do not exist in model.

Add the entries as follows.

```
name: { type: String, required: true },
email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
password: { type: String, required: true },
isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
resetPasswordToken: { type: String },
resetPasswordExpires: { type: Number }
```

Secondly, your query is wrong. The query should be like...

```
  const user = await User.findOne({
      resetPasswordToken: req.query.resetPasswordToken,
      resetPasswordExpires: {
        $gt: Date.now(), 
      },
  });
```

**Note**: Always check your database to see if your `update` entries are indeed updated.

#### Frontend

Upon verifying that the user + token exist, you can `res.status(200).send()` to your web app.

In your webapp, you will then request the user for the new password. Once user entered the new password, you will send the new password **AND** the token (again) to the backend.

This time, you will need to verify the token again before u update the password into user model. This will ensure the reset password is from a valid source.

you will probably want to delete resetPasswordToken and resetPasswordExpires from the document once password is updated since it's no longer needed.

Comment: So if I get it right, after checking the token with the get method, I have to post another method for updating the password, also it is k to find the user by id? So I know which one to update?

Comment: You do not find user by ID any more, you only identify the user by the token (assuming this is a very long unique hash that is not easily created), since you are resetting password base on the reset email (token).  After password is updated, you can redirect user to the login page to login with their username and the (newly updated) password. Do not log in automatically, you need to ensure the user resetting the password knows the username/email too for security reasons.